# Angular form custom validator messages causing error

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms

I have a custom validator for blacklisting words from form controllers:

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

const blacklist = ['poop']; 
export function Blacklist(control: AbstractControl) {

    let comment = control.value.split(' ');
    for (let i = 0, j = comment.length; i < j; i++ ) {
        if (blacklist.indexOf(comment[i]) !== -1) { // -1 = is no match in array
            return {
                validateBlacklist: {
                    blacklist: false
                }
            }
        } else {

        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Everything works great! But when I try to do a validation message I get:
`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'validateBlacklist' of null` on every key up unless it's a word in my blacklist array...

From this:

```
<div *ngIf="commentForm.controls['newComment'].errors.validateBlacklist && commentForm.controls['newComment'].touched">Error</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 1):

Error occurred due to ngIf condition.

Object `errors` doesn't have `validateBlacklist` object at the time of check and it's current value is null. Try `console.log(this.commentForm.controls['newComment'].errors)` first.

So it should look like this:

```
public isErrorOccurred(): boolean {
    if(
        'validateBlacklist' in this.commentForm.controls['newComment'].errors &&
        this.commentForm.controls['newComment'].touched
    ) {
        return 'blackList' in this.commentForm.controls['newComment'].errors.validateBlacklist;
    }
}
```

ngIf:

```
*ngIf="isErrorOccurred()"
```

Comment: it is `{minlength: {requiredLength: 2, actualLength: 1}}` for each keyup then when the word matches the validator it's `{validateBlacklist: {blacklist: false}}`

Comment: That's cool but I need to know how to show an error message for that specific error on that control. For this and learning purposes.

Comment: That's what this code do. It checks if exactly this type of error occurred and return boolean. If it exists it returns true and you can show your `div`. Just try to use it.